# How can I pull the year out of this NSString?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsrange

I have a number of NSStrings of movie titles like this:

```
@"Accepted (2006)"
@"Blade Runner (1982)"
@"(500) Days of Summer (2009)"
@"RoboCop (1987) - Criterion #23"
```

I am trying to get the four-digit numeric-only year that is always between ( and ) out of the title.

Whats the proper way to do this? NSRange? RegEx? Something else? Objective-C please, not Swift.

Comment: do you have a specific format? if you dont, you are risking false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this it is simpler to use the NSString method: rangeOfString:options: with the option NSRegularExpressionSearch with a look-behind and look-ahead based regex:

```
NSRange range = [test rangeOfString:@"(?<=\\()\\d{4}(?=\\))" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
NSString *found = [test substringWithRange:range];

NSLog(@"found: %@", found);
```

Output:

> found: 2006

For more information see the ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Answer (score 4):

Use a lookaround based regex.

```
"(?<=\\()\\d{4}(?=\\))"
```

or

Use capturing group.

```
"\\((\\d{4})\\)"
```

Since `(`, `)` are regex meta-characters, you need to escape those in-order to match the literal `(` or `)` symbols.

ie

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\((\\d{4})\\)" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *str = @"Accepted (2006)";
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
```